# ImportError: cannot import name ttk Python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy usando Sublime Text 3 para trabajar en un proyecto. Debo acotar que tengo poca experiencia.

Sólo pude configurarlo usando Python 3.0, estuve trabajando normalmente hasta que intenté importar ttk de tkinter, la consola me muestra un error... He revisado en la carpeta de Python y parece que tengo instalado el módulo. Quisiera saber si es un error de sintaxis, o hay algo que pueda hacer. Ya instalé el Python nuevamente en mi computadora. El mensaje es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede ayudar, estaré agradecida.

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega la porción de código en la que haces la importación para verificar que lo estes haciendo de la forma adecuada, recuerda que siempre puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608194/edit) tu pregunta. ;)

Comment: De todas formas verifica también la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules). ;)

Comment: Supongo que lo importas con `from tkinter import ttk`, si esto te da error ¿puedes importar tkinter sin problemas (`import tkinter;tkinter.Tk().mainloop()` deberia abrirte una ventana en blanco)? Una causa puede ser que no tengas instalado (o correctamente instalado) tkinter (no mencionas el sistema operativo que usas). Otra opción es que estés ejecutando el script con un interprete o entorno virtual diferente al que tiene el modulo instalado. Otra causa muy común es que **tengas alguna carpeta/modulo de python nombrado como "tkinter"/"tkinter.py" en la ruta del script que te da el error**.

Answer (score 0):

El error es que el modulo tkinter no se llama ttk, se llama tkinter y en consecuencia se importa con el siguiente comando

```
import tkinter
```

Pero si deseas el modulo ttk de tkinter, que contiene los widgets con tematica moderna entonces debes hacer

```
import tkinter.ttk
```

Y finalmente, si quieres ahorrarte tener que escribir toda esa linea cada vez que escribas una sentencia respecto al modulo, te conviene crearle un Alias al modulo para referirte a este de manera mas corta.

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
```

Eso es todo. Recuerda que ttk no es un modulo por si mismo si no que se encuentra dentro de tkinter